# Passing id from model to view Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-routing, backbone.js-collections

I am trying to get id from the collection to get passed to the view. I am able to get the model's information, just can't get the view to grab the data.

In my template each line has the model id:

```
<td><a href="#/process/<%= model.id %>"><%= model.name %></a></td>
```

My router looks like this:

```
var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
routes: {
    '': 'welcome',
    'process/:id': 'process'
}

});

var router = new Router();

router.on('route:process', function(id) {
  console.log('home page loaded');
  console.log(id);
  var processing = new Processes({id:id});
  processing.fetch({
    success: function(model,response){
        console.log(model.where({'id':id}))
    }
})
processView.render({id: id});
});
```

The right id is coming through but I can't get the view to retrieve the id.

This is my first project using Backbone.js

Comment: `fetch` is an AJAX call so the model won't be around until the `success` callback is triggered.

Answer (score 1):

The id / model attributes will not be available to you until the fetch (http://backbonejs.org/#Model-fetch) method  call returns since it is an Ajax call done asynchronously.

**Hence all actions that need to happen after data is fetched from the server should be placed inside the success / error (for error handling) callbacks**.

In your case, the call to render view should be moved inside the success callback as bel.

```
processing.fetch({
    success: function(model,response){
        console.log(model.where({'id':id}))
        processView.render({id: id});
    }
});
```